# how to store the images in the mysql table and retrieval of stored image using php code?

Tags: php, mysql, image

i need help that how to store the images in the mysql table and retrieval of stored image using php code...

sample code that helps me a lot..

regards
~Deepu~

Comment: Lacking details, is http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql what you mean?

Comment: I would not recommend storing them in your database.  I would recommend storing them in the file system and storing the path to the image in your database.

Comment: It is not recommended, It makes the table bulky, But it can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410631/11766145

Answer (score 1):

Create a table in database with *Blob* field and another varchar field for picture type  (jpeg/gif/etc..), store the picture in there.

To store the picture do the following:

1. Read the picture into variable. Either `fread` of `file_get_contents`
2. Insert picture data and picture type into database

To retrieve picture back do regular select statement to get the picture data and file type.
Set the header `Content-type` to appropriate file type and display the picture data.

For example:

HTML
`<img src="getPicture.php?id=12345" />`

PHP

```
<?php
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
// Assume $db is out DAL that is already connected and can query database 
$img = $db->loadObject("SELECT pic_data, pic_type FROM picture WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");

// We get the following
// $img->pic_type = 'image/jpeg'
// $img->pic_data = 'picture data'

//
//
// Make sure there is not output prior setting header
header("Content-type: $img->pic_type");
echo $img->pic_data;
```

Look at this page. There is code it will help you http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_(blob_storage).xml

Answer (score 0):

**To store the image directly in the table...**

Onchange event can be used to preview the selected image.

After form submit the image is temporarly stored in **$_FILES['user_photo']['tmp_name']**,  **file_get_contents()** and **base64_encode()** are two internal functions to get the content of the image and convert it to base64,

Then the image is stored in the mySQL table by insert query and the entire table is fetched by running the select query and displayed in the table.

Create a table in the database with three fields id, name, and image. Set **PRIMARY KEY** for id, set **VARCHAR(30)** for name and **LONGBLOB** for image.

**SQL Query for creating a table**

```
CREATE TABLE `image_database` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
`image` LONGBLOB NOT NULL ,    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));
```

preview.html

```
<body>
  <form method="post" action="actionPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose an Image</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="user_photo" onchange="preview()"/></td>

            <td><img src="" width="100px" height="150px" id="frame"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preview(){
        frame.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Give Your SQL(PHP myAdmin) **User Name, Password & Database Name**.

actionPage.php

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user_name = "root"; //Enter your database user name
    $db_password = "*****"; //Enter the password
    $db_name ="__________"; //Enter your database name

    $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user_name, $db_password, $db_name);

    $firstName=$_POST["firstName"];
    $image=$_FILES['user_photo']['tmp_name'];

    $image=file_get_contents($image);
    $image=base64_encode($image);

    $insert_query="INSERT INTO image_database(name, image) VALUES ('$firstName', '$image')";
    $db_connection->query($insert_query);

    $select_query="SELECT * FROM image_database";
    $result = $db_connection->query($select_query);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row=$result->fetch_row()){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'"; width="100px"; >';?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```